# I want to show array 5 biggest in 10 data

Tags: php, arrays

My Code is :

```
$dataBerita = array(
 'Babakan' => array(5),
 'Babakan Pasar' => array(30),
 'Bantar Jati' => array(70),
 'Baranang Siang' => array(50),
 'Batutulis' => array(40),
 'Bojongkerta' => array(25),
 'Bondongan' => array(90),
 'Ciampea' => array(5),
 'Cibadak' => array(2),
 'Cilubang' => array(6)
);

array_multisort($dataBerita, SORT_DESC);

foreach ($dataBerita as $key => $value) {
 echo $value.", ";
}
```

I want to display the 5 largest data arrays out of 10 data arrays, as follows :

```
90,70,50,40,30,
```

Comment: If the array already sorted them use `array_slice` to get the first 5 elememt

Comment: If one of the answer helped you please mark it as "accepted" (the grey "v" mark at the left of the post) so other may know to use it in the future. (same goes for your previous posts)

Answer (score 0):

change your `foreach` to

```
foreach (array_slice($dataBerita,0, 5) as $key => $value) {
    echo $dataBerita[$key][0].',';
}
```

Comment: Why the echo in the look using the array + key and not `$value`?

Comment: Thanks you very much for your answer, its working:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort and splice the array by removing all except first 5

```
$top = 5; // you can change it anytime
array_multisort($dataBerita, SORT_DESC);
array_splice($dataBerita, -(count($dataBerita)-$top));
```

[array_splice](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) — Remove a portion of the array and replace it with something else

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [Bondongan] => Array
        (
            [0] => 90
        )

    [Bantar Jati] => Array
        (
            [0] => 70
        )

    [Baranang Siang] => Array
        (
            [0] => 50
        )

    [Batutulis] => Array
        (
            [0] => 40
        )

    [Babakan Pasar] => Array
        (
            [0] => 30
        )

)
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/40597e042e2cb7def9b35e5028c072fe39c8ff31).